# get row index from link button in footer template

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am frustated with this problem with Gridview.

I want to get row index in **RowCommand** event of gridview when linkbutton present in **footer row** is clicked.

I always get -1 as value in `index`

```
        Control ctl = e.CommandSource as Control;
        GridViewRow CurrentRow = ctl.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
        int index = CurrentRow.RowIndex;
```

How to get out of this problem ?

Comment: Need the index of footer row?

Comment: i wan t row number .. so yes

Comment: Can you add `OnClick` event for `LinkButton` and find `index` with `((GridViewRow)((LinkButton)sender).NamingContainer).RowIndex`

Comment: but i want value in rowcommand event of gridview ..

Comment: Then can you add `CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"` and find index by `e.CommandArgument`.

Comment: no....doesnot work , gives -1 always..already tried..

Comment: maybe you need to handle this by `GridView.Rows.Count`

Comment: Isn't a footer row always at the bottom and thus you cant determine index by getting Rows.count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from what I know the footer row will have always the RowIndex = -1. I've tried to do some tests, you can try it also, and for each row of DataRow type, we'll have an RowIndex, but for the row of FooterRow type, we'll have always -1 value. Below it's my test code(it's for information purposes only, some lines of code are not needed).

```
protected void grdGrid_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            Control ctl = e.CommandSource as Control;
            GridViewRow CurrentRow = ctl.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
            int index;

            foreach (GridViewRow row in grdGrid.Rows)
            {
                if (CurrentRow.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    //you'll have an RowIndex for each DataRow: 0,1,2 and so on
                    index = CurrentRow.RowIndex;
                }
                else if (CurrentRow.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
                    {
                        //the RowIndex will be always -1 
                        index = CurrentRow.RowIndex;
                    }

            }
        }
```

I hope this will help you.